# Using Z3 with concrete arrays

Tags: z3

I want to use Z3 to solve this problem:

Given two arrays, a and b, of equal size with concrete values, select the index that meets these constraints:

```
0 < selection < [length of array]
forall i, a[selection] <= a[i]
forall i, b[selection] >= b[i]
```

My z3py program looks like this:

```
def selectIndex(array1, array2):
   n= len(a) #assume both lists are same size
   s = Solver()
   selection = Int('selection')
   i = Int('i')
   j = Int('j')
   a= Array('a', IntSort(), IntSort())
   b= Array('b', IntSort(), RealSort())

   for idx in range(n):
      Store(a, idx, array1[idx])
      Store(b, idx, array2[idx])

   constraint1 = And(selection >= 0, selection <= n)
   constraint2 = And(i >= 0, i <= n)
   constraint3 = And(j >= 0, j <= n)
   constraint4 = ForAll([i], a[selection] <= a[i])
   constraint5 = ForAll([j], b[selection] >= b[j])

   s.add(And(constraint1, constraint2, constraint3, constraint4, constraint5))

   s.check()
   m = s.model()
   return m[selection].as_long()
```

The model always returns 0, even when given input arrays for which there is only one selection that meets the constraints. I don't think it is using the concrete values in the arrays a and b. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with this example, but the crucial one is that the `Store(...)` expressions do nothing. The result of `Store(...)` is a new array expression that represents an old array (`a`, `b`) with one of the indexes (`idx`) updated to a new value (`array1[idx]`, `array2[idx]`). Currently these new arrays are discarded, but we can save them:

```
for idx in range(n):
    a = Store(a, idx, array1[idx])
    b = Store(b, idx, array2[idx])
```

Further, I think that

```
    constraint1 = And(selection >= 0, selection <= n)
```

should not include the index `n`, i.e., the `<=` should be `<` and the constraints on `i` and `j`

```
constraint2 = And(i >= 0, i <= n)
constraint3 = And(j >= 0, j <= n)
```

are unnecessary.